# How do I convert and 14.04 ISO DVD to the installation Disk?

Tags: iso

How do I convert my ISO DVD of Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop 64 version to a DVD that will install the 14.04 Ubuntu operating system?

Comment: Why you need to convert an iso to a "dvd"?

Answer (score 0):

the question suggests you don't know how to burn a cd/dvd

on windows use: [cdBurnerXP](http://www.chip.de/downloads/CDBurnerXP_13008371.html)

on ubuntu use: apperantly you can right click on the iso and then "write to disk" [click here for more information](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)

when starting your pc you will have to open bootmenu. usually with f8 or delete key.